# cannot cross-compile a c++11 program with multithreads using cmake

Tags: compiling, g++, cmake

When I first tried to run the program, I got the following output:

This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

so, I edited my CMakeLists.txt file as it looks and got my program running from terminal:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(foo)

find_package(qibuild)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-std=c++11 -pthread")


qi_create_bin(foo "main.cpp")

qi_create_test(test_foo "test.cpp")
```

But, still, I am not able to cross-compile this program as I get the following output:

```
Using toolchain: cross-atom
* (1/1) Building foo in Debug
Scanning dependencies of target test_foo
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test_foo.dir/test.cpp.o
i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu-g++: no input files
/bin/sh: 1: -std=c++11: not found
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_foo.dir/test.cpp.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_foo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[ERROR]: BuildFailed Error occurred when building project foo
```

I have exhaustively searched through the internet and no progress! Can someone help me? thanks!